# How to fetch private room list using ejabberd (using their API and/or using XML)?

Tags: xml, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, converse.js

I know I can retrieve a list of public rooms from my server using:

```
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    id='zb8q41f4'
    to='chat.shakespeare.lit'
    type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>
```

[XEP-0045 - Discovering Rooms](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-rooms)

However, I need a list of all rooms, regardless whether is public or private, and if is online of not.

Any suggestions, specially through XML?

Comment: If the room is not configured with `muc#roomconfig_publicroom` then it won't show up in the service discovery - that's the whole point behind this configuration option.

Comment: They are not public. I know that using that code above I'm not supposed to retrieve that list. What i need is a way to retrieve the private ones.

Answer (score 1):

> They are not public. I know that using that code above I'm not supposed to retrieve that list. What i need is a way to retrieve the private ones.

When a MUC admin requests the list of rooms, he gets all the rooms, including the private ones.

You can also get the full list of rooms with this ejabberd command:

```
$ ejabberdctl muc_online_rooms muc.localhost
privateroomcreatedbyuser1@muc.localhost
privateroomcreatedbyuser3@muc.localhost
publicroomcreatedbyuser1@muc.localhost
publicroomcreatedbyuser3@muc.localhost
```

Those commands can be executed with XML-RPC or ReST calls if you enable the corresponding modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Muc-Sub](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/extensions/muc-sub/), then in ejabberd 21.04 there is a new api /api/get_user_subscriptions to get all the subscribed rooms list of a user. You can see [Api Documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#get-user-subscriptions)